# MinMax function (Mathematica v10.1.0) conflicts with NDSolve`FEM`MinMax?

Tags: bugs, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 10.1.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

Some problem in v10.1.0 (Windows 8.1 x64) and the new `MinMax`...

```
MinMax[{0.2`, 0.375`, 0.55`, 0.7250000000000001`, 0.9000000000000001`,
   1.`, 0.2`, 0.9`, 1}]
```

> {0.2, 1.}

Now

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
MinMax[{0.2`, 0.375`, 0.55`, 0.7250000000000001`, 0.9000000000000001`,
   1.`, 0.2`, 0.9`, 1}]
```

> MinMax[{0.2, 0.375, 0.55, 0.725, 0.9, 1., 0.2, 0.9, 1}]

This happens because `NDSolve FEM MinMax` shadows the newly added `System MinMax` and because `NDSolve FEM MinMax` doesn't supports mixed `Integer` and `Real` arguments.

Of course, it's better to be specific always:

```
System`MinMax[{0.2`, 0.375`, 0.55`, 0.7250000000000001`, 
  0.9000000000000001`, 1.`, 0.2`, 0.9`, 1}]
```

> {0.2, 1.}

## UPDATE

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.   The mentioned
>   conflict is a known issue and our developers are aware of it. I have
>   added your contact information to the existing report so you can be
>   notified when this is resolved.   Thank you once again for taking the
>   time and bringing this to our attention.   Sincerely,
>
> [...]
>
> Wolfram Technical Support Wolfram Research
>   http://www.wolfram.com/support/

Comment: The "bug" is that there is no shadowing warning when the `NDSolve\`FEM` package is loaded. Then the user would know to use the full name.

Comment: I hope we can do better in some near future instead of prepending System`` to every MinMax call.

Comment: Have you reported this?

Comment: @Kuba No, still waiting other opinion about how to call "this"... Apparently Bob Hanlon doesn't consider this a "bug" or something to be reported.

Comment: @unlikely Well, ask WRI about an opinion about how to call this :)

Comment: As a more convenient workaround, you could put ``NDSolve`FEM` `` after ``System` `` in `$ContextPath`.  For example ``Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; $ContextPath = RotateLeft[$ContextPath]`` is an easy way.  Of course it gives the FEM functions the lowest priority, but maybe that's ok.

Comment: @Kuba, We have an opinion, it's an "issue" :), a "known issue".

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/function-in-mathematica-10-1-but-not-in-cdf-player-10-0-2

Comment: This is a bug and fixed in the development version. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21) in the comments, this is now fixed in version 10.2.

```
In[1]:= MinMax[{0.2`, 0.375`, 0.55`, 0.7250000000000001`, 0.9000000000000001`, 
                1.`, 0.2`, 0.9`, 1}]    

Out[1]= {0.2, 1.}

In[2]:= Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

In[3]:= MinMax[{0.2`, 0.375`, 0.55`, 0.7250000000000001`, 0.9000000000000001`, 
                1.`, 0.2`, 0.9`, 1}]

Out[3]= {0.2, 1.}
```